# truncated doubles getting long decimals in for loop in java

Tags: java

I have two double values that are truncated to two decimal spots. Each one represents a spot on a radian circle, and they are either supposed to increment or decrement by `0.01` until they find a target value. Here's the code:

```
    BigDecimal negPath = new BigDecimal(roundAndConvert(pendA.getTheta()));
    BigDecimal posPath = new BigDecimal(roundAndConvert(pendA.getTheta()));
    BigDecimal target = new BigDecimal(roundAndConvert(pendB.getTheta()));
    for (negPath = negPath; ((negPath.doubleValue() > -0.01) && (!negPath.equals(target))); negPath = negPath.subtract(new BigDecimal(0.01))) {}
    for (posPath = posPath; ((posPath.doubleValue() < 6.29) && (!posPath.equals(target))); posPath = posPath.add(new BigDecimal(0.01))) {}

//here's the method that rounds the values

public double roundAndConvert(double value)
{
        double holder = (int)(value*100) / 100.0;
        if (holder < 0)
        {
            while (holder < -6.28) {holder += 6.28;}
            holder += 6.28;
        }
        else
        {
            while (holder > 6.28) {holder -= 6.28;}
        }
        return holder;
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the two Path values are returning doubles with long decimals, like so:

```
pos = 6.299999999999944
neg = -0.01999999999996656
```

The values that they return aren't like this before the for loop, so I think it has to do with the increment/decrement.

EDIT: tried replacing the doubles with BigDecimals, but now the program is freezing at the for loops. I see the stringCache for the Path values, and they still have the long decimals.

EDIT: Another change to the coding, this time using all `BigDecimal` objects and `equals` in the for loops, but I'm still getting long decimals.

EDIT: finally worked with the coding shown. The accepted answerer explains what I was doing wrong. Here's the code that works:

```
    for (negPath = negPath; ((negPath.doubleValue() > -0.01) && (!negPath.equals(new BigDecimal((int)(target.doubleValue()*100)/100.0)))); negPath = negPath.subtract(new BigDecimal(0.01))) 
    {
        negPath = new BigDecimal((int)(negPath.doubleValue()*100)/100.0);
    }
    for (posPath = posPath; ((posPath.doubleValue() < 6.29) && (!posPath.equals(new BigDecimal((int)(target.doubleValue()*100)/100.0)))); posPath = posPath.add(new BigDecimal(0.01))) 
    {
        negPath = new BigDecimal((int)(negPath.doubleValue()*100)/100.0);
    }
```

Comment: There's an *entire website* dedicated to this kind of problem: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
for (negPath = negPath; 
      ((negPath.doubleValue() > -0.01) && (negPath.doubleValue() != target));
      negPath.subtract(new BigDecimal(0.01))) 
{}
```

I see two bad errors here. First:

```
negPath.subtract(new BigDecimal(0.01))
```

should be

```
negPath = negPath.subtract(new BigDecimal(0.01))
```

because a `BigDecimal` is immutable - each operation on them just creates a new one. This might be the case why your loop never terminates now - because the state does not change in each loop.

Second:

```
(negPath.doubleValue() != target)
```

Comparing doubles that way is a no-no, because intermediate rounding-errors are quite sure to happen and then this part of the condition is never true.

**Rationale**: Please read some basic documentation about floating point calculations - floats are not just numbers as you know them from mathematics, they must be treated with great care.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I edited the answer already just after submitting the first version. SO does not show this as an edit - so just reload the page.

Comment: Made the change to the increments and decrements as suggested, but they are still returning long decimals

Comment: @RaysonK: But the loops do not block anymore ... one step in the right direction. But your comments show, that you did not read the links about floating point handling. And _mixing_ BigDecimal and float/double is even worse. I propose you adjust your code _completely_ to BigDecimal and post it. Fixing one error after the other is not possible in the comments and also not in the chat.

Comment: Alright, it did work after putting a certain piece of code in the for loop, but you gave me most of the answer to this problem, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal instead of double.

Comment: @raysonk: Freeze as in not terminate, or freeze as in take a long time to complete? Note that `BigDecimal` will require about three times as much memory as `double`, and may run at least an order of magnitude more slowly.

Comment: Has to be not terminate. Tried another method without BigDecimal, and it did the same thing.

Comment: I suspect that you might be better of using `BigDecimal` and letting us help you figure out why it doesn't terminate.

Comment: Operate only with BigDecimals.  Don't go converting them to doubles when it's time to do comparisons or arithmetic with them.  Keep doubles right out of your code.